# Как поместить картинку в QTabWidget, чтобы она занимала весь таб

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4

Как поместить картинку в QTabWidget, чтобы она занимала весь таб?

[image]

Comment: За что минусуем? За что закрываем? Видно же градиентные поля по бокам и внизу от белого - вопрос как сделать, чтобы их не было и картинка занимала всё пространство.

Comment: Поясните подробнее как именно должна размещаться картинка? Таб должен быть размером с картинку или наоборот картинка размером с таб?

Comment: картинка должна быть размером с таб и картинка должна занимать весь таб

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `void QTabWidget::setTabIcon(int index, const QIcon& icon)` для установки картинки на ваш таб. Размер можно задать так: `void QTabWidget::setIconSize(const QSize& size)`.

Comment: серые поля все равно видны

Comment: Тогда наследуйте свой класс от `QTabWidget` и переопределяйте функцию `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* ev)`

Answer (score 1):

Stylesheet tab 1

```css
border-image: url(:/img/qq.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте в `stylesheet`

```
QTabBar::tab {padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
```